# Firebird exception in Delphi WideStringType OutParameter

Tags: delphi, parameters, firebird

I have sample firebird stored procedure

```
PROCEDURE PROCEDURE01
RETURNS (
 PARAMETER01 VARCHAR(50))
AS 
BEGIN
  PARAMETER01 = 'Hello';
END
```

and in the Delphi side

```
LCommand := SQLConnection1.DBXConnection.CreateCommand;
LCommand.CommandType := TDBXCommandTypes.DbxStoredProcedure;
LCommand.Text := 'PROCEDURE01';
LIdOut := LCommand.CreateParameter;
LIdOut.ParameterDirection := TDBXParameterDirections.OutParameter;
LIdOut.DataType := TDBXDataTypes.WideStringType;
LIdOut.Name := 'PARAMETER01';
LCommand.Parameters.AddParameter(LIdOut);
LCommand.Prepare;
LReader := LCommand.ExecuteQuery;
```

and receive exception

"Arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation"

Comment: `WideString` implies multi-byte characters, and your parameter is set to `VARCHAR(50)`, which typically is single-byte characters. Try using compatible types. (Do you REALLY TYPE ALL YOUR STORED PROCEDURES IN ALL CAPS? If so, I'm glad I don't have to work with your SQL - SHOUTING MAKES THINGS HARD TO READ. They invented the Shift key For a reason.)

Comment: @Ken White, it is common practice to write UPPER CASE keywords in Firebird. It's just an old habit I guess, so no need to shout.

Comment: @LightBulb: Except they're not all keywords. `PROCEDURE01` is not a keyword, and neither is `PARAMETER01'. There's no requirement to write in upper-case, especially in a stored procedure where there's no possible ambiguity between the SQL and non-SQL statements. Text, whether it's an SQL statement or a plain sentence in an email or web post, is hard to read when it's typed in all caps. :-) And I didn't accuse the poster of shouting at us, but of shouting in general. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It seems a limitation of the [TDBXCommand](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DBXCommon.TDBXCommand) (or maybe of the Dbexpress firebird driver), because using output parameters of another types all works fine. As workaround you can use the [`TSQLStoredProc`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.SqlExpr.TSQLStoredProc) class.

Try this sample.

```
var
 LSQLStoredProc :  TSQLStoredProc;
begin
  LSQLStoredProc:=TSQLStoredProc.Create(nil);
  try
    LSQLStoredProc.SQLConnection:=SQLConnection1;
    LSQLStoredProc.StoredProcName:='PROCEDURE01';
    LSQLStoredProc.ExecProc;
    ShowMessage(LSQLStoredProc.ParamByName('PARAMETER01').AsString);
  finally
    LSQLStoredProc.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: +1 for providing a "proper" way of calling stored procedures from code. IMO, OP used a bit uncommon way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

SET the database to UTF-8 as an example.

```
CREATE DATABASE localhost:mybase
  USER SYSDBA
  PASSWORD masterkey
  PAGE_SIZE 8192
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET UTF8;
  SET NAMES ISO8859_1;

CREATE TABLE scales (
  ID ...,      
  byteken VARCHAR(50) COLLATE DE_DE,
```

look at my answer at [Arithmetic exception, numeric overflow, or string truncation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10122073/dbexpress-no-key-specified)

Answer (score -1):

first put "SUSPEND" before "END" in stored procedure

Comment: I inserted suspend but result is same

Comment: SUSPEND need for returning values from stored procrdures, so why you down my carma?

Comment: I did not down-vote ("down your carma"), but it's probably because there's really no useful information in your answer. It either needs to contain much more detail about **why** this would be a solution, or it should be deleted and posted as a comment. It's not a complete answer, it's 8 words with no reason or information behind them.

Comment: `SUSPEND` is not necessary for procedures that only return 1 value. It would probably be wrong here, because procedures containing SUSPEND are treated differently from procedures without (one is selectable, the other is not).